# How to make it so that from the Kubernetes pod the traffic on a certain IP goes first to the host and then to the another server database

Tags: kubernetes

there's a database that's available on a private network.
there is a pod with an application that cannot access the database because it is not on the database network.
is there any way to route the traffic coming from the pod so that it can connect to the database without hostNetwork: true?

i tried set hostNetwork: true, it works but i think it not best idea